# How can I get format of an audio file in android

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

How can I get the format of audio file.

I need to check the format of audio file to satisfy a condition

I am using **Firebase** so I can't check by cutting string.

Comment: please upvote the answer too for the community

Answer (score 0):

There's metadata of all the files on Firebase storage. There are various getter methods for the files' metadata. Please check it out - https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata